# How to create an event that triggers a lambda function in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm working on a project that involves storing videos into individual S3 Buckets when the user uploads videos. I also plan to process these videos using AWS Elastic Transcoder in a AWS Lambda function.  I want to create an event that will trigger the lambda function in Node JS so that I can change the source bucket without having to manually do it in the Lambda interface. How can I do this using Node JS?

I tried to find how to code up an event for a lambda function and trigger it, so I couldn't find anything so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can create s3 trigger using [s3 event notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/EventNotifications.html).

You can use create event for the following notifications

Currently, Amazon S3 can publish notifications for the following events:

```
New object created events
Object removal events
Restore object events
Reduced Redundancy Storage (RRS) object lost events
Replication events
S3 Lifecycle expiration events
S3 Lifecycle transition events
S3 Intelligent-Tiering automatic archival events
Object tagging events
Object ACL PUT events
```

You can follow this guide to achieve : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

For this question I am assuming that you have already deployed your lambda function.